# Make div fill the remaining space

Tags: css, html

This question has been asked a million times but I can't seem to find the solution for my specific version.  Here is what I have:

```
<div>
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
    <div id="div3"></div>
</div>
```

div1 and div2 are always shown and div3 is only sometimes shown.  div2 and div3 have fixed widths. I want div1 to fill the remaining space that div2 and possible div3 are not taking up.  I want them to appear in the above order left to right ([div1][div2][div3]).

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: can you show your css as well

Comment: I've tried a bunch of different variations for the css and nothing has worked.  I'm open to anything that will make it work.  That being said, I will add a little.

Comment: I can't think of something at the top of my head that are not media queries that don't involve SOME Javascript, would you be okay with that?

Comment: We need much more info on what you're trying to do, this is the result of what you've provided: http://jsfiddle.net/N5gD6/... And, assuming you're using floats: http://jsfiddle.net/N5gD6/1/

Comment: This sounds exactly like a table to me. Although it's an interesting CSS astronaut challenge in its own right.

Comment: Javascript solution would be fine. CSS would be better, but I thought a bit of js might be required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer:**

See in action: http://jsfiddle.net/C9Q3F/3/

```
<style>
    div { height:100px; }
    #div1 { background-color:red; }
    #div2 { background-color:blue; width:75px; float:right; }
    #div3 { background-color:green; width:100px; float:right; }
</style>
​
<div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
    <div id="div3"></div>
    <div id="div1"></div>
</div>​
```

**Explanation:**

The reason this works, is - the order of the divs changed - so it writes `div2` and `div3` to the page, both with fixed widths, and both `float`ing.  So by the time `div1` is written (now last), it's default 100% width will fill the 100% of the available width.  Since the other divs are taking up their space already, the "available width" is what's left.

**For other cases (eg. last div fills space):**

If you want the last div to fill the remaining space instead of the first, like this question/answer, just tweak it to use `float:left;` instead of `float:right;` and change the div order and widths - same concept as this and works just fine.

Comment: I believe div1 is the one that takes all the available space, not div3 ?

Comment: Correct, div1 needs to fill the remaining space

Comment: @Nick Olsen - Revised answer and example - I believe it's correct now, as div1 doesn't have a width, but takes up the remaining space that div2 and div3 do not take up.

Comment: Genius!  Now for extra points, why in the world does that work?

Comment: It works because I told it to.  Does it need any other reason?  ;)

Comment: @NickOlsen - Explanation added - hope I explained that clearly enough.

Comment: That actually makes sense.  Thanks for the explanation,